# Absolutely position element on page EVEN IF parent element has position:relative or absolute

Tags: css

See http://jsfiddle.net/u9qj0k9t/10/ for an example.

I'm trying to create a context-menu tied to a generic element on a page.  I have no control over how that element is laid out on the page however.  The context menu works fine if whatever element wrapping it does not have a position:absolute/relative attached to it, but when it does the popup shows up relative to the top-left corner of the element instead of the page.  I realize this is by design, but I was hoping there was some css trick to absolutely position an element on a page REGARDLESS of how how it is contained.

```
<div>
    Comment<br/>
    Comment<br/>
    Comment<br/>
    <div style="position:relative;"> <!-- have no control over this-->
        <div id="customUIElement">
            <span id="placeHolder">Click Me</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
$("#placeHolder").bind("click", function(e){
    var m = $("#popup");
    if(!m.length){
        var m = $("<div id='popup'></div>");
        $("#customUIElement").append(m);
    }
    m.css("height",100);
    m.css("width",100);
    m.css("background-color","#ff0000");
    m.css("zindex",9999999);
    m.css("position","absolute");
    m.css("top", e.pageY);
    m.css("left", e.pageX);
    m.html("Hello, world");
    m.fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u9qj0k9t/13/)**

I would simply ***not*** append the *popup* to that element,
 but to the ***page***:

```
$("#placeHolder").on("click", function(e){
    var m = $("#popup");
    if(!m.length){
        m = $("<div id='popup' />");
        $('body').append(m);
    }
    m.css({
        height:100,
        width:100,
        backgroundColor:"red",
        zIndex:9999999,
        position:"absolute",
        top: e.pageY,
        left: e.pageX
    }).html("Hello, world").fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Comment: I was trying to keep the DOM of the element self-contained since there are potentially several instances of these on the page, but this solution will work as long as they all have unique IDs